# taking arrays from nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, luhn

```
const batch = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4, valid5, invalid1, invalid2, invalid3, invalid4, invalid5, mystery1, mystery2, mystery3, mystery4, mystery5]


// Add your functions below:


function validateCred(array) {
  let sumArray= [] 
  for (i=0; i < array.length ; i++){
    //console.log(i)
    if (array.length%2 !==0 ) {
    if(i%2 !==0) {
      if(array[i]*2 < 10){
        sumArray.push(array[i]*2)
      } else{
        sumArray.push(array[i]*2-9)
      }
    } else {
      sumArray.push(parseInt(array[i],10))
    } 
    } else { if(i%2 ===0) {
      if(array[i]*2 < 10){
        sumArray.push(array[i]*2)
      } else{
        sumArray.push(array[i]*2-9)
      }
    } else {
      sumArray.push(parseInt(array[i],10))
    }
    }
  }
  if(sumArray.reduce( (prv, cur) => prv + cur) % 10===0) {
return true
  }else{
    return false
  }
}

function findInvalidCards(nestedArray) {
  let nestedArrayInvalid= [] ;
  for(i=0; i < nestedArray.length; i++){
   if(validateCred(nestedArray[i]) === false){
      nestedArrayInvalid.push(nestedArray[i])
    } 
  } 
 return nestedArrayInvalid 
}

console.log(findInvalidCards(batch))
```

i am writing a credit card checker, the luhn algorithim function is complete but now im trying to take a nested array and all invalid card to be added to an array as seen in the second function but it just doesn't seem to work, i have no idea what's wrong

Comment: I'm not quite getting where exactly those nested arrays you're talking about are. Would you elaborate a bit? Also, expected result would be nice to grasp the whole concept.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your `validateCred()` function is returning data, but when its returning either true or false on an element by element basis, `findInvalidCards()` seems to be working as expected:

```js
const batch = [true, false, false, true, true]


// Add your functions below:


function validateCred(arrayItem) {
   return arrayItem
}

function findInvalidCards(nestedArray) {
  let nestedArrayInvalid= [];
  for(i=0; i < nestedArray.length; i++){
   if(validateCred(nestedArray[i]) === false){
      nestedArrayInvalid.push(nestedArray[i])
    } 
  } 
 return nestedArrayInvalid 
}

console.log(findInvalidCards(batch))
```